# Property value of 'null' cannot be read

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make the variable **userName** retain the value of whatever is typed into the input **name_enter**. But when I try to do so I just get the console error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null*

```
function questionName() {
    document.write("<p>Hi my name is Bot9000. What is your name?</p><input type='text' id='name_enter' /><input type='button' value='Enter' onClick='verifyName();' />");
}

var userName = document.getElementById("name_enter").value;

function verifyName() {
    document.write("<p>Your name is " + userName + "?</p>");
    document.write("<input type='button' value='Yes' onClick='nameVerified();' /> <input type='button' value='No' onClick='questionName();' />");
}

function nameVerified() {
    document.write("Nice to meet you " + userName + ". <br />Do you have any Hobbies?");
}
```

Comment: you should call questionName before initializing userName

Comment: `name_enter` doesn't exist until you call `questionName`. Even if it did, you're grabbing the value *right away* instead of waiting for the user to type anything in. Meaning, `userName` will always be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for the value of name before the function questionName is called and adds the form to the page.

try

```
function questionName() {
    document.write("<p>Hi my name is Bot9000. What is your name?</p><input type='text' id='name_enter' /><input type='button' value='Enter' onClick='verifyName();' />");
}



function verifyName() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("name_enter").value;
    document.write("<p>Your name is " + userName + "?</p>");
    document.write("<input type='button' value='Yes' onClick='nameVerified();' /> <input type='button' value='No' onClick='questionName();' />");
}

function nameVerified() {
     var userName = document.getElementById("name_enter").value;
    document.write("Nice to meet you " + userName + ". <br />Do you have any Hobbies?");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't wish to call the var userName twice. But this works, so thank you!

I also already had the function questionName() called onLoad of my html document.

Comment: If that is the case, inside the function questionName you can also apply a keyUp event to the input field and set the userName value globally as the user types. There are many ways to go about it, your instinct to not tackle the dom twice is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That Error means the `getElementById()` method couldn't find the element you specified. This can be caused by:

1. JS code was executed before the Element was created
2. The Element dosn't exist.

In your case you have problem #1. To fix this call your function that creates the element first:

```
function questionName() {
    document.write("<p>Hi my name is Bot9000. What is your name?</p><input type='text' id='name_enter' /><input type='button' value='Enter' onClick='verifyName();' />");
}

function verifyName() {
    document.write("<p>Your name is " + userName + "?</p>");
    document.write("<input type='button' value='Yes' onClick='nameVerified();' /> <input type='button' value='No' onClick='questionName();' />");
}

function nameVerified() {
    document.write("Nice to meet you " + userName + ". <br />Do you have any Hobbies?");
}

questionName();
var userName = document.getElementById("name_enter").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that your code can have is the order in which the functions are executed. So to have it clean just save the element into the variable and not the value. Like

`var userName = document.getElementById("name_enter");`

Then where ever you want to access the value of the input just use `userName.value`

---

Also refactoring your code a little bit.

```
function questionName() {
    document.write("<p>Hi my name is Bot9000. What is your name?</p><input type='text' id='name_enter' /><input type='button' value='Enter' onClick='verifyName();' />");
}

questionName() // execute this function so that the input element is added into the DOM   

var userName = document.getElementById("name_enter"); //just save the element because you haven't typed in any value into it so you will not get any value anyways at this moment.

function verifyName() {
    document.write("<p>Your name is " + userName.value + "?</p>");
    document.write("<input type='button' value='Yes' onClick='nameVerified();' /> <input type='button' value='No' onClick='questionName();' />");
}

function nameVerified() {
    document.write("Nice to meet you " + userName.value + ". <br />Do you have any Hobbies?");
}
```